# Add a cancel button to my action on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying to add a cancel option on my display alert that will cancel the action. Currently when the user clicks the submit button the data is posted to the azure database and the display message appears with "Feedback Added, Your symptom feedback has been added", and the user can select 'ok' or 'cancel'  but the data is already added and they do nothing. Is there a way i can set it so that the user has to select 'ok' to add the data and can select a 'cancel' option which cancels the action . This is my current code with submits the data to the database:

```
 async Task AddSymptomFeedback(string usersymid, string value)
    {

        symptomFeedback.Usersymptomid = usersymid;
        symptomFeedback.Intensity = value;
        symptomFeedback.UserID = Helpers.Settings.UserKey;
        symptomFeedback.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        symptomFeedback.Datetimelimit = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).ToString("g");

        try
        {

            await symptomFeedbackManager.AddSymptomfeedback(symptomFeedback);
           await DisplayAlert("Feedback Added", "Your symptom feedback has been added", "OK", "Cancel");



            await Navigation.PushAsync(new newviewsymptom());
            Navigation.RemovePage(this);
            HasAdjustedSl1ider = false;

            //We have to null the id so that we are not always updating the existing feedback item
            symptomFeedback.Id = null;

            //Refresh the List View 
            //await GetUserSymptoms();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", ex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
```

And this is the code behind my submit button:

```
       async void SubmitFeedback_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


         if (rangeSlider == null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Add feedback", "Please add feedback for the symptom", "OK");
        }

        else

        {
            await AddSymptomFeedback(rangeSlider.IDValue, rangeSlider.Value.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass two param `Ok` and `Cancel`. Handle both button click as below

```
var response = await DisplayAlert("Title", "Message", "Ok", "Cancel");
if (response == true) {
//Yes action
} 
else 
{
//No action
}
```

As OP asked how to use

```
async void SubmitFeedback_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
var response = await DisplayAlert("Title", "Message", "Ok", "Cancel");
if (response == true)
{
//Yes action
await AddSymptomFeedback(rangeSlider.IDValue, rangeSlider.Value.ToString());
} 
else 
{
//No action
}
}
```

Comment: if you want to prompt the user when they click the button, then the DisplayAlert would go in the button's click handler

Comment: @MarkPW - If user clicks button and you want to show Alert, then it should be inside click event. I tried to edit my answer check it.

Comment: @CGPA6.4 That did it, Thanks, Appreciate it .

Comment: @CGPA6.4 will do. Do you know if there is a way that you can add for example the rangeSlider.Value.ToString value within the display alert text ?

Comment: @CGPA6.4 i can only post once every 90 minutes :(